# Passing an xml file in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to pass a basic xml file in Powershell. 
It contains the path to some folders which I need to access.

```
$XML = [xml] (get-content F:\practice\XML Files\xml1.xml)
$main = $XML.Root.File[0].Path
Get-ChildItem $main
```

But I get the following error -

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\SAMSUNG\System.Xml.XmlElement' because 
it does not exist.
```

Can anyone tell me what this error is and the solution to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert in PowerShell, but it seems like you are just supplying Get-ChildItem with an object.

Maybe you can try

```
    $XML.Root.File[0].Path.Value
```

and if that doesnt work the below example that I use in my own powershell scripts that reads from an XML file

```
    (Select-Xml -Content $XML -XPath "your xpath here").Node.Value
```

From your example your XPath should look something like

```
    //Root/File[0]/Path
```